# Install Stylus manually in Node.js with Cygwin

Tags: node.js, cygwin, stylus

after a few tries I successfully install nodejs in windows with cygwin...

And when I find out that I can't install npm in windows, I wonder...

How can I install the Stylus manually??
I downloaded the files from [the Stylus Github Site](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus)

**Where do I copy them??

What commands should I use in the cgywin to install it??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is too late, but good news everyone! NPM runs on windows without cygwin now :-)

http://npmjs.org/doc/README.html